# Javascript and css minifier inbuilt in studio 2010, asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, css, minify

Is there any tool which can combine all js files and minify them at build time, same for css?

We currently do it on release version but it involves lot of manual labor(I just spend 3 hours doing it and then testing).

Edit:

Just after posting this question i found this

[.net java yui port](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)

But leaving question open, please share your experience if you have used it. Any other better tool?

Comment: Personally I prefer to incorporate closure for JS combination/minification and YUI for the CSS minification as part of the build, once it's setup it's *much* better than having any manual steps.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx), it'll combine and optionally compress your scripts and stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

[mx ajax minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584) will minify both js and css files and can be set up as a build task. and i'm pretty sure you can use it to combine files but i haven't looked into that.